# How can I print ■ in visual studio c?

Tags: c, printf, extended-ascii

I want to print ■(in ascii code 254) in c visual studio project with function printf, but my program can't print. Just like(? instead of ■)

My program can print ascii character 32 ~ 128.

I think since 129~254 is extended ascii, it requires more code(header?other function?).

How can i print ■? help me please.

here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned char count;
    for (count = 32; count < 255; count++) {
        printf("  %3d - %c", count, count);
        if (count % 6 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here it prints alright on Visual Studio 2019. Do you have changed any configurations on your project?

Comment: Check which code page your console window is set to

Comment: No, I just used the Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 just same. And no changes in code

Comment: Oh, i was using korean in console so it can't print 129~255. I have solved problem by adding #include<Windows.h> and system("chcp 437"); 

######  system("chcp 437") is change language of dos window(cmd)
thank you!

Comment: You'll probably want to use `wchar_t` and wprintf instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have solved by adding system("chcp 437"), which changes language Korean to English in cmd(dos window).

here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
int main() {
    unsigned char count;
    system("chcp 437");
    for (count = 32; count < 255; count++) {
        printf("  %3d - %c", count, count);
        if (count % 6 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```